# showing data with left join and where not in clause

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

1. cluster

   - idcluster
   - namecluster
2. grade

   - idcluster
   - idjury
   - point
3. jury

   - idjury
   - namejury

the jury table will give a point, and will be saved to the grade table.
I want to display cluster data that has not been assessed by the jury in where clause by idjury

I have tried use simple left join
for example, I have 1 data inserted into the grade table

```
idcluster | idjury | point

1         | 1      | 300
```

cluster table

```
idcluster | namecluster

1         | cluster a

2         | cluster b

3         | cluster c
```

jury table

```
idjury | namejury

1      | hary

2      | potter
```

and this code that I expect to show cluster data, where cluster data has not been assessed using "where `idjury` not in"

```
SELECT cluster.namecluster, grade.point, grade.idjury
FROM `cluster` 
LEFT JOIN grade
ON cluster.idcluster = grade.idcluster 
WHERE idjury NOT IN (1) //how to display data clusters that have not been assessed by a jury table (by idjury)
```

so this is what I want

```
idcluster | namecluster | point | idjury

2         | cluster b   | null  | null

3         | cluster c   | null  | null
```

when not using where clause

```
idcluster | namecluster | point | idjury

1         | cluster b   | 300   | 1

2         | cluster b   | null  | null

3         | cluster c   | null  | null
```

when using "WHERE idjury NOT IN (1)" no data displayed

Comment: I still don't understand the bit about 'this is what I want'

Comment: I have revised my question, I adding cluster data table and jury data table @Strawberry

Comment: My comment came after your edit

Answer (score 0):

put your condition in on clause instead of where

```
SELECT cluster.namecluster, grade.point, grade.idjury
FROM `cluster` 
LEFT JOIN grade
ON cluster.idcluster = grade.idcluster 
and idjury NOT IN (1)
```

Comment: showing 3 data, but all rows in idjury showing null

Comment: @yudistiralarungtino, could you please add your both's table data in your question

Comment: done sir, i adding jury data table and cluster data table

Answer (score 0):

You should add `OR idjury IS NULL` to the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT cluster.namecluster, grade.point, grade.idjury
FROM `cluster` 
LEFT JOIN grade
ON cluster.idcluster = grade.idcluster 
WHERE idjury NOT IN (1) OR idjury IS NULL
```